# Spring Boot 2 + OAuth2: Configure Exchange of Auth Code for Token

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, okta

I've followed this [Spring Boot OAuth2](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_manual) tutorial on configuring an OAuth2 client. Unfortunately, once a "user" authenticates with the Idp (Okta) a redirect with a "code" takes place that results in a redirect loop of: `/login -> /authorize... -> /login... -> /login`

**Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.**

Does anyone know what is or could be the issue and how to solve it? Details follow.

Okta configuration:

> Login redirect URIs: http://localhost:8080/auth/login
>
> Logout redirect URIs:
>   http://localhost:8080/auth/logout
>
> Login initiated by: App only
>
> Initiate login URI: http://localhost:8080/auth/login

The configuration properties are:

```
okta:
  oauth2:
    client:
      client-id: clientId
      client-secret: clientSecret
      scope: openid profile email
      client-authentication-scheme: form
      access-token-uri: https://mydomain.oktapreview.com/oauth2/myapp/v1/token
      user-authorization-uri: https://mydomain.oktapreview.com/oauth2/myapp/v1/authorize
    resource:
      user-info-uri: https://mydomain.oktapreview.com/oauth2/myapp/v1/userinfo
```

The filter is:

```
  private Filter filter() {
    OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
        "/login");
    OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(oktaClient(), oauth2ClientContext);
    filter.setRestTemplate(restTemplate);
    UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(oktaResource().getUserInfoUri(),
        oktaClient().getClientId());
    tokenServices.setRestTemplate(restTemplate);
    filter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);

    return filter;
  }
```

The *WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter* configure is:

```
  @Configuration
  @EnableOAuth2Client
  public class WebSecConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  ....
  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/logout**", "/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui",
            "/configuration/security", "/swagger-resources/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and().exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login")).and().csrf()
        .csrfTokenRepository(
            CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and().addFilterBefore(filter(),
        BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
  }
  ....
  }
```

**Update:**
Solution was to change `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login")` to `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/")` and re-create the authorization server.

Comment: Please update your question with main class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the default authorization server, or one you created. If you use the default, it should look something like:

```
https://mydomain.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default
```

Comment: I created a new auth server and the issue is now a redirect loop. Any ideas on problem/solution?

Comment: I’d suggest using an Okta tutorial to solve your problem. I’ve written several so I might be able to help. What’s your use case? Do you just want login in a Spring Boot app with Spring Boot 2 / Spring Security 5?

Comment: The end goal is to have Spring Boot 2 based APIs (using Spring Security + OAuth2) authenticate/authorize users of a single-page-app. On authentication, I'd like to have the JWT returned to the SPA. And with every request, I'd like the API(s) to valid the JWT and verify authorization via the "groups" claim that is included in the JWT. When the JWT has expired I'd like the token to be refreshed, via the refresh token.

Comment: I used one of your [tutorials](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/03/21/spring-boot-oauth) with a [simple Spring tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_simple) to get authentication working via `@EnableOAuth2Sso`. When I execute a `GET` request to the root path, i.e. `/` I get all entire `Principal` class contents, expect the refresh token, even though it is configured in Okta's authorization server. I have yet to figure out how to valid the JWT & verify authorization via the "groups" claim that is included in the JWT or how to refresh.

Comment: Spring Security (and Otka's Spring Boot starter) are designed to handle submitting the refresh token for you to get a new access token. As far as the groups claim, you could do it like we do in JHipster: https://github.com/mraible/jhipster-oidc-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/okta/developer/web/rest/AccountResource.java#L69

Comment: To clarify, Spring Security (OAuth2) and Okta Spring Boot both _independently_ handle getting new access token(s) via a refresh token? Currently, the `Principal` object returned as per your tutorial above does _not_ include any "groups" key - even though the Okta auth server is configured to include that claim. Is that expected behavior? With respect to groups claim, can it be extracted in a filter and added to Spring Security's role context so it may be accessed via `hasRole`? Do you happen to know of an example of such?